# java 8 make a stream of the multiples of two

Tags: java, math, java-8, java-stream

I'm practicing streams in java 8 and im trying to make a `Stream<Integer>` containing the multiples of 2. There are several tasks in one main class so I won't link the whole block but what i got so far is this:

```
Integer twoToTheZeroth = 1;
UnaryOperator<Integer> doubler = (Integer x) -> 2 * x;
Stream<Integer> result = ?;
```

My question here probably isn't related strongly to the streams, more like the syntax, that how should I use the doubler to get the result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Stream.iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-).

```
Stream<Integer> result = Stream.iterate(twoToTheZeroth, doubler);
```

or using the lambda directly

```
Stream.iterate(1, x -> 2*x);
```

The first argument is the "seed" (ie first element of the stream), the operator gets applied consecutively with every element access.

EDIT:

As Vinay points out, this will result in the stream being filled with 0s eventually (this is due to int overflow). To prevent that, maybe use `BigInteger`:

```
Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ONE, 
               x -> x.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2)))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Hey! Running it gives me 0 all the time.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati Are you sure you didn't set `twoToTheZeroth` to 0? Oh, and you will get 0 after `Integer.MAX_VALUE` was reached.

Comment: I ran `    Stream<Integer> result = Stream.iterate(1, x -> x * 2);
        result.forEach(System.out::println); ` and output is 0 all the time?

Comment: @VinayPrajapati Try `Stream.iterate(1, x -> 2*x).limit(32).forEach(System.out::println)` (to avoid int overflow) or `Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ONE, x -> x.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2))).forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: But why 0 if i don't set a limit? It could have been some exception but it prints 0 only all the time

Comment: @VinayPrajapati Because of integer overflow. You'll still get ints, but those will turn first negative, then 0, which will remain at 0 when multiplied.

Comment: Or stop when the `int` range is exhausted: `IntStream.range(1, 31).map(i -> 1<<i)` By the way, `Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ONE, i -> i.shiftLeft(1))` is likely more efficient than `Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ONE, x -> x.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2)))`…

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5).stream().map(x -> x * x).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

so you can use the `doubler` in the `map` caller